# Count missing values in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL, how can I select the missing values from a table?

**Summary**: How many instances of a `string a` have type `Battle` which don't have a type `Activity`, in which there are many instances of `string a`.

See image below. For the query below, I queried for type `Battle` and then `Activity` and the rows highlighted in **red** have overlap. The rows highlighted in **blue** are the rows for type `Battle` which I need to know are present or not for type `Activity`.

**Question**: So from this example, how do I return all 6 rows which aren't present for type `Activity`?

[image]

Here's the query:

```
select count(vocab_id), vocab_match, player_response, player_response_target, response_id
from (
    select v.id as vocab_id, vocabulary as vocab_match, sq.id as response_id, sq.amatch as response_match, sq.player_response, sq.player_response_target, sq.dialog, sq.dialog_target
    from vocabulary_es v
    right join (
        select trim((regexp_matches(a.player_response_target, '\[t-(.*?)\]', 'g'))[1]) as amatch, a.id, a.player_response, a.player_response_target, a.dialog, a.dialog_target, a.event_type
        from (
            select drena.event_type, r.id, r.player_response, r.player_response_target, d.dialog, d.dialog_target
            from dialogresponses dr
            left join responses r on (r.id = dr.response_id)
            left join dialogs d on (d.id = dr.dialog_id)
            left join dialogresponses_eventsnpcs_all drena on (drena.dialogresponse_id = dr.id)
            where dr.locale_id = 1
            and dr.response_id IS NOT NULL
            and drena.event_type = 'Battle'
        ) as a

        order by a.id asc
    ) as sq
    on (trim(v.vocabulary) ilike trim(sq.amatch))
    where v.vocabulary IS NOT NULL

) as final
group by vocab_id, vocab_match, player_response, player_response_target, response_id
order by response_id asc;
```

Comment: I just don't get it.  What does the question have to do with the query you have presented?  Sample data and desired results are really helpful in explaining a problem.  I have no idea what "Battle" and "Activity" mean or how they are represented in your data model.  Or what these concepts have to do with "dialogs" and "vocabulary".

Comment: Your question is confusing because you change names, terms and example values arbitrarily within the same question. Focus on *one* consistent example, remove irrelevant columns, declare your version of Postgres and start with a table definition for your example (`CREATE TABLE ...`).

Comment: Maybe something like: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE event_type="Battle" AND struct_match NOT IN (SELECT struct_match FROM table WHERE event_type="Activity");`